# Can I have two CasADi problems in one C++ program?

Tags: c++, ipopt

I currently run an IPOPT optimization problem via the CasADi interface. I generate the compiled CasADi files (libcasadi_solver.c & libcasadi_solver.so), link CasADi through CMakeLists, and call their csolver function through a wrapper.cpp:

```
nlpsol("csolver", "ipopt", "libcasadi_solver.so", solve_opts);
```

I want to have a second problem solved through this CasADi interface within the same C++ program. I thought I could accomplish this by generating different libcasadi_solver files, say libcasadi_solver_1 and libcasadi_solver_2.

The compiler doesn't like this however, throwing error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcasadi_solver

Interesting that lcasadi_solver is not same as libcasadi_solver... I'm thinking these names are setup in the casadi installation/configuration. Maybe I need two installations to run two different problems? Seems like the wrong idea. I will not be calling these problems in parallel, so I believe I don't need to worry about thread-safe programming.

Any help, suggestions thoroughly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution:

In CMakeLists, 'casadi_solver' was listed in target_link_libraries().

It turns out cmake prepends 'lib' to these items. I did not understand that this item was a direct instruction for cmake to find 'libcasadi_solver.so.'

I removed this item entirely from target_link_libraries(); it appears unnecessary.

Cheers! and happy to hear other ideas if there's a more correct way to hack this.